# LeetCode 924: Minimize Malware Spread

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem copied here. If you would like to review, please do so. Thank you for your time!

#### Problem

> In a network of nodes, each node i is directly connected to another
> node j if and only if `graph[i][j] = 1`.
>
> Some nodes `initial` are initially infected by malware.  Whenever two
> nodes are directly connected and at least one of those two nodes is
> infected by malware, both nodes will be infected by malware.  This
> spread of malware will continue until no more nodes can be infected in
> this manner.
>
> Suppose `M(initial)` is the final number of nodes infected with
> malware in the entire network, after the spread of malware stops.
>
> We will remove one node from the `initial` list.  Return the node that
> if removed, would minimize `M(initial)`.  If multiple nodes could be
> removed to minimize `M(initial)`, return such a node with the smallest
> index.
>
> Note that if a node was removed from the `initial` list of infected
> nodes, it may still be infected later as a result of the malware
> spread.

#### Inputs

```
[[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[0,0,1]]
[0,1]

[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1]]
[3,1]

[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
[0,2]

[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
[1,2]
```

#### Outputs

```
0

3

0

1
```

#### Code

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Solution {
    std::vector<int> parents;
    inline int minMalwareSpread(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &graph, const std::vector<int> &initial) {
        size_t length = graph.size();

        for (size_t index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            parents.push_back(index);
        }

        for (size_t row = 0; row < length; row++) {
            for (size_t col = row + 1; col < length; col++) {
                if (graph[row][col]) {
                    union_uf(row, col);
                }
            }
        }

        std::vector<int> areas(length, 0);
        std::vector<int> malwares(length, 0);

        for (size_t area = 0; area < length; area++) {
            areas[find(area)]++;
        }

        for (size_t init : initial) {
            malwares[find(init)]++;
        }

        std::vector<int> min_spread = {1, 0};

        for (int init : initial) {
            min_spread = std::min(min_spread, {(malwares[find(init)] == 1) * (-areas[find(init)]), init});
        }

        return min_spread[1];
    }

private:
    const inline size_t find(const size_t x) {
        if (x != parents[x]) {
            parents[x] = find(parents[x]);
        }

        return parents[x];
    }

    const inline void union_uf(const size_t x, const size_t y) {
        parents[find(x)] = find(y);
    }
};
```

#### Algorithm

You can read about various algorithms here [in this link](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimize-malware-spread/solution/):

- We'd first map the graph using Disjoint Set Union (DSU).
- We'd count all areas as well as all infected sets.
- If there'd be only one malware set, we would return the largest. Otherwise, we'd return the set with lowest index using the last loop.

#### References

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimize-malware-spread/)
- [Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimize-malware-spread/solution/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimize-malware-spread/discuss/)
- [Union Find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

Comment: Hi Emma, Could you please add some algorithmic explanation about your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Function prefix qualifiers

I seem to remember this being covered in your reviews before, but:

```
const inline size_t find(const size_t x)
```

This benefits from neither of the `const` declarations nor the `inline`. Both the return value and the argument are passed-by-value scalars and do not benefit from `const`. `inline`, for all intents and purposes, has no effect, particularly where a compiler is told to optimize your code - and even if it *did* have an effect, it's a bad idea to tell the optimizer what it should and shouldn't inline. It will understand what's good for your code better than the programmer does 99% of the time.

If these concepts are confusing or difficult to apply to code on a practical basis, that is understandable - feel free to ask follow-up questions.